# addEventListener('exit') to inappbrowser in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, cordova

I'm trying to exit out of my application when the inappbrowser closes. I'm trying to do so by adding a eventlistener to the browser, and then from there.. maybe like exit(0) or something.
But it's not working, the alert is never reached.

Does somebody know why?
Also if you have a better idea on how to exit the app when the inappbrowser closes, please share.

I'm using phonegap.

```
var ref = null;

ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_self', 'location=no');
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert("hello");});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use **"_blank"** instead of **"_self"**. The 'exit' event wont fire if external source opened in the existing view.

To exit the app use

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```

Complete code:

```
 var ref = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=no');

     ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event){  Exit(); });

 function Exit(){
              navigator.notification.confirm(
                'Do you want to exit app?',  
                function(i){
                    if(i==2)
                     {
                       navigator.app.exitApp(); //This will Close the App
                     }
                },              
                'App Name',            
                'Cancel,Exit'          
              );
 }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to the loadstop event for inappbrowser doesn't get fired in a _self loaded inappbrowser either.